# Angle between specified arc lengths

Tags: geometry

I'm looking to understand why this seems to be correct and if not, why; as I need to be able to scale this concept across several different parts at work.

If I have a flattened object with specified arc lengths for the outer and inner arc drawn on a piece of paper with a given angle between them and I cut it out and mate the ends of the arcs, do I get an angle between the planes that the arcs sit on that is equal to the angle that was between them in the flattened state? Example of flattened object below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is about how a conical helix is made by bending to a cone from its development.

[image]

The shortest distances along 2D in plane blue lines are conserved as  the shortest distances along red 3D cone helix curves. Let us see how this happens.

Take a semicircle cut out from paper along a diameter and its semi circle arc. Join the radii of length $L$ to form a cone  of base radius $r$ and apex angle $\alpha= \sin ^{-1}\frac{r}{L}$ where lengths $L$ are the cone generators.

Let the angles subtended by arc at base center and apex be $ \theta, \phi$

Since arc length is same,

$$r \theta = L \phi,\quad  \frac{r}{L}=\frac{\phi}{\theta} =\sin \alpha $$

If at cone apex then semi vertical angle (SVA) = $\alpha$
$$ \sin \alpha= \frac{r}{L}= \frac{180^0}{360^0}=\frac12$$
So we get a $30^0$ semi vertical angle cone from its development.

In this case we are talking about a cone of SVA

$$= \sin^{-1}\frac{346^0}{360^0}\approx 74^0$$

that is almost flat.

To obtain  the equation of the red helix line in 3D ( what is pictured is a projection on unbent original plane ), distance conservation leads to *Clairaut's Law* which needs to be integrated.